# Snowflake sql query running long time

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

trying to select all the columns from three views using join in snowflake. Query running for more than 45mins. All the three base views are constructed on top of one json table. The flattened data is separated across three views according to their type. When trying to combine the view the query is running for a long time

Comment: Please add to your question (1) the table/view definitions of all objects involved (2) the EXPLAIN PLAN output. What size warehouse are you using to run this query?

Answer (score 0):

In general, Snowflake executes queries quickly and doesn't require intervention, so often a slow query is the symptom of a mistake in the way the query is written. The following is a list of things to check to identify the cause of slow-running queries.

1. Is the query queuing, i.e. not executing at all? [See Understanding
   Queuing](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Understanding-Queuing).
2. Is the query spilling to local or external storage? [See
   Recognizing Disk Spilling](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Recognizing-Disk-Spilling)
3. Is the query creating more rows than expected? [See Recognizing Row Explosion](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Recognizing-Row-Explosion)
4. Is the query not using pruning as well as it could? [See How to Recognize Unsatisfactory Pruning](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-recognize-unsatisfactory-pruning)
5. Are there problems with the join order? [See Controlling Join Order](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Controlling-Join-Order)
6. Sometimes the expectations for the query performance are based on having it seen running very quickly in the past. [Check Understanding Result Caching](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Understanding-Result-Caching)

The following articles clarify specific topics:

1. [Improve Performance of JDBC Metadata Operations](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Improve-Performance-of-JDBC-Metadata-Operations)
2. [Estimating Time Needed to Clone Large Objects](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Estimating-Time-Needed-to-Clone-Large-Objects)